# Storing the returning value in the calling script

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i am new to javascript and i am playing around to understand this language , I am rying to learn more of object oriented javacript . I m trying to build a small script , but i hit a difficulty ,let me share what i have .

Basically i have this library that i am building , a tiny one, i have the following function . (My library is in Mapster.js):

```
addMarker : function(opts){
                var marker;
                opts.position = {
                    lat : opts.lat,
                    lng : opts.lng
                } 
                marker = this._createMarker(opts);
                if (opts.event) {
                    this._on({
                        obj : marker,
                        event : opts.event.name,
                        callback : opts.event.callback
                    });
                }
                return marker;
            },
```

so basically in the end the above function returns marker.

now in my script.js , the file in which i will be actually using my library of Mapster.js , i have the following lines of code :

```
map.addMarker({
    lat: 15.4989,
    lng: 73.8278,
    draggable : true,
    visible : true,        // true this to false and the marker will dissapear
    event: {
        name    : 'click',
        callback : function(){
            alert('yups i am gautam');
        }
    }
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content : 'I am On a Map'
});

infoWindow.open(map.gMap , marker); // i get an error saying ReferenceError: marker is not defined
```

well fair enough , i asked a seniour colleage of mine and he said the following :

> As the message says, you haven't defined marker . In addMarker you
>   create it and return it, but you're not assigning that returned value
>   in the calling script.

I guess he gave away the asnwer with that but i am still struggling with , "how do i store the returning value in the calling script , I.E. scripts.js" .

I would be really greatful , if somebody can answer this question for me .

Thank you.

Alexander.

Comment: @downvoter , updated , please check .

Comment: Like your colleague said you have to *assign* the returned value. I.e. you need a `var marker = map.addMarker(....` The name you happen to give a returned variable is only relevant *inside* that function. Outside that function you need to put it in another variable (which can have the same name - or different, because they won't clash).

Comment: @MattBurland Lesson learnt . Thanks

Comment: @Guys ! Keep calm and Upvote .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the result of `addMarker` to a variable:

```
var marker = map.addMarker({
    lat: 15.4989,
    lng: 73.8278,
    draggable : true,
    visible : true,        // true this to false and the marker will dissapear
    event: {
        name    : 'click',
        callback : function(){
            alert('yups i am gautam');
        }
    }
});

infoWindow.open(map.gMap , marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is probably referring to the fact that simply having a function call on a function that returns an object it doesn't mean that object will now exist in the scope were the call was made, e.g. the following code:

```
function returnObj()
{
    var obj = {sMessage: 'Hello World'};
    return obj;
}
returnObj();
console.log(obj.sMessage);
```

will result in a referrence error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined"  because even if the call returns an object if the result is not assigned to a variable in the new scope, it will be lost; you will need:

```
var oReturnObj = returnObj();
console.log(oReturnObj.sMessage);
```

So in your above example you should check that **marker** variable passed in the 
**infoWindow.open(map.gMap , marker);** call holds the result of the **map.addMarker();** before passing it as parameter(I presumed that your library main object, e.g. **map** object exists at the moment of your code execution, e.g.  Mapster.js file was already loaded and executed).